# Working with JSONArrays: how do i convert to ArrayList<String[]>

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, casting

I have json that looks like the following

```
{  
   "tiles":[  
      {  
         "header":"Manual",
         "subheader":"Login",
         "summary1_label":"",
         "summary2_label":"",
         "summary3_label":"",
         "summary4_label":"",
         "summary1_value":"",
         "summary2_value":"",
         "summary3_value":"",
         "summary4_value":"",
         "iconUrl":"http://x.x.x.x\/icon1.png"
      },
      {  
         "header":"NewUser",
         "subheader":"Login",
         "summary1_label":"",
         "summary2_label":"",
         "summary3_label":"",
         "summary4_label":"",
         "summary1_value":"",
         "summary2_value":"",
         "summary3_value":"",
         "summary4_value":"",
         "iconUrl":"http://x.x.x.x.x\/icon2.png"
      },
      {  
         "header":"Facebook",
         "subheader":"Login",
         "summary1_label":"",
         "summary2_label":"",
         "summary3_label":"",
         "summary4_label":"",
         "summary1_value":"",
         "summary2_value":"",
         "summary3_value":"",
         "summary4_value":"",
         "iconUrl":"http://x.x.x.x/icon3.png"
      }
   ]
}
```

I cast this as a JsonObject and send it to a reformating method. in that method i do the following

```
public ArrayList<String[]> formatHttpResponse_SummaryTile(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<String[]> arrayList_summary = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    JSONArray tilesArray = json.getJSONArray("tiles");
    //JSONObject allTilesData = json.getJSONObject("tiles");
    for (int i=0; i<tilesArray.length(); i++)
    {
        //JSONObject thisJsonObject = tilesArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray thisJsonArray = tilesArray.getJSONArray(i);
        String[] thisStringArray = new String[thisJsonArray.length()];
        for (int j=0; j<thisJsonArray.length(); j++)
        {
            thisStringArray[j]=thisJsonArray.getString(j);
        }
        arrayList_summary.add(thisStringArray);
    }
    return arrayList_summary;
}
```

As you can see i create an array list then cycle through my jsonObjects 3 children. Now the problem is that i want to convert the children to String[][ but my code bugs out at `JSONArray thisJsonArray = tilesArray.getJSONArray(i);` as it isnt a jsonArray.

Any idea how i can get the children above into 3 string arrays all added to a arrayList Is there a more efficent, straight cast i can do?

Comment: what do you mean "bugs out"

Comment: you should make your json data more readable. Try this one [JSON Formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: apologies, the SO editer removed some spacing. I will

Comment: picblood - it errors, doesnt like the cast.

Comment: Json more readable now

Comment: This is not a JsonArray in this line you are trying to get from the json Array in the i-th index. `JSONArray thisJsonArray = tilesArray.getJSONArray(i);` It's a JSON Object with Key Value Pairs.

Comment: yes i understand my bug now but how do i do it correctly, how do i get that into a string[] so that i can add that new string[] to a arrayList<String[]>

Comment: So if you are trying to get the JSONObject as String, you can use it's  ,method. `toString()`

Comment: And the other thing is, json object is key value pairs, do you want to get it's keys or values as String ? make the question more clear.

Comment: Agreed with osayilgan - you question doesn't really make much sense. You have a JSON object which contains 1 name/value pair ( the name being "tiles and the value being a JSON array). Each element of the array is a JSON object each with 11 name/value pairs. There is no way you can directly parse the original JSON string int `ArrayList<String[]>` and still have it as a logicall representation of the original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<String[]> formatHttpResponse_SummaryTile(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
            JSONObject thisJsonObject = tilesArray.getJSONObject(i); //create jsonObject to grab values from
            Iterator<String> iter = thisJsonObject.keys();
            String[] thisStringArray = new String[thisJsonObject.length()];
            int count=0; //track which element we are on in the dest string[]
            while (iter.hasNext())
            {
                String key = iter.next();
                try
                {
                    String value = (String)thisJsonObject.get(key);
                    thisStringArray[count] = value;
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    // Something went wrong!
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
            arrayList_summary.add(thisStringArray);
}

return arrayList_summary;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that 'for' loop got cut. It is the same as yours.

Comment: I am not sure either. An upvote or accepting as answer would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Of course, im away from comp but will test it out in a fw hrs. :)

Comment: Oh wait, i should have been more explicit regarding one aspect - i want to be able to cycle through the objects nodes and not have to call them out specifically eg jsonObject[i] instead of jsonObject.getString("header") - is this possible?